# Null pointer exception of Dagger-2 (android)

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

### Details

Null pointer Exception on UseContex class while using 'printToast()' method of UseContex class.UseContex class extends the mainActivity.If i print toast in MainActivity than it doe's not contain null pointer on context object but same thing don in UseContex than it show null pointer exception.

### AppComponent

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
void inject(DaggerApplication daggerApplication);
void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
```

}

### AppModule

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
private final DaggerApplication application;
public AppModule(DaggerApplication application) {
    this.application = application;
}
@Singleton
@Provides
Context providesApplicationContext(){
    return  application;
}
@Singleton
@Provides
UseContex provideUsecontex(){
  return new UseContex();
}
}
```

### UseContex

```
public class UseContex extends MainActivity{
public  void printToast(){
Log.e("User dao impl","Hello user dao");
Toast.makeText(context, "helo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Inject
UseContex useContex;
@Inject
public Context context;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    
((DaggerApplication)getApplication()).getAppComponent().inject(this);
     useContex.printToast();
}
}
```

## DaggerApplication

```
public class DaggerApplication extends Application {
AppComponent appComponent;
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new 
AppModule(this)).build();
    appComponent.inject(this);

}
public AppComponent getAppComponent(){return  appComponent;}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dagger is not injecting your `UseContex` subclass because `AppComponent` does not `@provide` a `UseContex`. `AppComponent` is only `@providing` a `MainActivity` and you're passing in a `UseContex` as its polymorphic base class and hoping that that works. Instead, `@provide` a `UseContex` in your `AppComponent` and Dagger will inject your base class fields.

Comment: if i do @provide  UseContex  in my AppComponent than it shows a error

Comment: Yup, you will need to add a @Provide method in AppComponent that returns a UseContex

Comment: Thank you for the best answer. Could you try my answer in your other question as well?

Answer (score -1):

It is showing null pointer because context is not define in UseContex class.
You have to use "getApplicationContext" in place of "context" in this line

```
Toast.makeText(context, "helo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

replacement

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, "helo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```